# UNUserNotificationCenter Completion Was Never Called Swift

Tags: swift, unusernotificationcenter

I have the following code blocks in my AppDelagate:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier {
            print ("Message Closed")
        }
        else if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
            print ("App is Open")
        }

        // Else handle any custom actions. . .
    }

func showMessage()

    {
        let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notification.title = "Test"
        notification.subtitle = "This is a test"
        notification.body = "I need to tell you something, but first read this."
        notification.categoryIdentifier = "TESTAPP"
        notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification1", content: notification, trigger: notificationTrigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }


func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self

        self.showMessage()


    }
```

My notification comes up and when I click on the notification to open the app, the app opens up and the console shows this:

> App is Open
>
> 2017-07-23 14:48:56.182 Form[3255:198009] Warning:
>   UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to
>   -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:
>   but the completion handler was never called.

So it looks like my print to type out "App is open" it displaying but I am getting the completion handler error right below it.

Comment: Just write `completionHandler()` where you wrote "// Else handle any custom actions. . .". It's because either *you* need to write that `completeionHandler()` to tell compiler you're done. If you don't you'll be keeping the app open for a longer period of time and have to wait for OS to kill you...wasting battery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add completionHandler() under your code in

> userNotificationCenter

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier {
        print ("Message Closed")
    }
    else if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
        print ("App is Open")
    }

    // Else handle any custom actions. . .
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: When I close the notification, `if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier {
            print ("Message Closed") ` does not get called. Do you know why?

Comment: @Martheli it should be an identifier like "AdumbIdentifierName"...What you wrote is a **class** type

Comment: @Honey is action identifier the same as category identifier?

Comment: @Martheli you can debug it and see why your code doesnt works,or print the identifier to see. Honey is corrent look at correct identifier to check.

Comment: @Martheli categoryIdentifier is a different thing. It's to be used for adding actions/buttons to the notification. First try getting the actionIdentifier right. If you still wanted to know more read [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250) and watch this [WWDC2016: Introduction to Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707). If you were still interested then also watch [WWDC2016: Advance Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708). The videos are NOT a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you call the completion handler within the method to let the system know you are done processing the notification.

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier {
        print ("Message Closed")
    }
    else if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
        print ("App is Open")
    }

    // Else handle any custom actions. . .

    // Execute completion handler
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: When I close the notification, if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier { print ("Message Closed") does not get called. Do you know why?